# MySQL Link 1 Row to multiple

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my scenario:

I have `Requests` linked to `Projects`.

And I have `Users` linked to `Projects` (to more than 1, this is the problem).

So this is the scenario:

```
Users                 
-------
Name
Password
Project_ID


Projects
---------
ID
Name


Requests
----------
Description
Project_ID
```

And I need, for a given User, to fetch all the requests, the problem is that I want Users.Project_ID to be 1,2 (attached to project 1 and 2).

And do something like:

```
SELECT Description
FROM Requests
    INNER JOIN Projects ON Requests.Project_ID = Projects.ID
    INNER JOIN Users ON Projects.ID = Users.Project_ID
```

The problem is what I said before, 1 User can have multiple projects.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that the `project_id` contains two ids 1 and 2 in the same string value in the database like `1,2`?

Comment: Some sample table data and expected result, and it will be much easier to understand your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SEE SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3684d/5)**

Left join is to show the users which no projects too

```
select u.name, group_concat(r.description) as all_projects
from users u
left join requests r
on r.project_id = u.project_id
inner join projects p
on p.id=r.project_id
group by u.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need userwise report.

```html
<table border=.5 >
  <tr>
    
    <th>
      UserName
      </th>
    <th>
      Projects
      </th>
    <th>
      Requests
      </th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Sample user
      </td>
    <td>
      1,2
      </td>
<td>
      ongoing,Completed
      </td>
    </tr>
  
  </table>
```

```
SELECT Users.Userid as UserID,
       Users.Name as User,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Projects.ID) as project,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Description) as Request
    FROM Requests
        INNER JOIN Projects ON Requests.Project_ID = Projects.ID
        INNER JOIN Users ON Projects.ID = Users.Project_ID
    GROUP BY Users.Userid
```

Assuming `Userid` as key for Users. Hope this helps